# PDOStatement::bindValue- SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After troubleshooting **`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`** issue from the prepared statement below. 

I found there is an issue about **`$stmt->bindValue`**.

---

**Prepared Statement & BindValue - 1**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
   'SELECT *
    FROM `gcm_notification` t1
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `latest` 
        FROM `gcm_notification` 
        WHERE `registration_id` = :registration_id 
        GROUP BY `post_id`) t2
    ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`latest`
    LEFT JOIN `posts` t3 ON `t1`.post_id = `t3`.ID
    WHERE `registration_id` = :registration_id
    GROUP BY `post_id`'
);

$stmt->bindValue(':registration_id', $registration_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Result**

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`

---

**Prepared Statement & BindValue - 2**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
   'SELECT *
    FROM `gcm_notification` t1
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `latest` 
        FROM `gcm_notification` 
        WHERE `registration_id` = :registration_id 
        GROUP BY `post_id`) t2
    ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`latest`
    LEFT JOIN `posts` t3 ON `t1`.post_id = `t3`.ID
    WHERE `registration_id` = :registration_id
    GROUP BY `post_id`'
);

$stmt->bindValue(':registration_id', $registration_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':registration_id', $registration_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Result**

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031`

---

**Prepared Statement & BindValue - 3**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
   'SELECT *
    FROM `gcm_notification` t1
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `latest` 
        FROM `gcm_notification` 
        WHERE `registration_id` = :registration_id 
        GROUP BY `post_id`) t2
    ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`latest`
    LEFT JOIN `posts` t3 ON `t1`.post_id = `t3`.ID
    WHERE `registration_id` = :registration_id_1
    GROUP BY `post_id`'
);

$stmt->bindValue(':registration_id', $registration_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':registration_id_1', $registration_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Result**

`SUCCESS`

---

I do not understand why the **Prepared Statement & BindValue - 1** does not work. `bindValue` cannot bind 2 same parameters which is `:registration_id`?

So, I assume my hypothesis for first point is correct and I copy and paste another `bindValue` and try which is **Prepared Statement & BindValue - 2**. The result was failed again.

I assume it might because of the parameter got conflicts. So, I create rename the parameter into `registration_id` and `registration_id_1` which is **Prepared Statement & BindValue - 3** and it is working.

Would someone mind to explain to me what is actually happening?

Thank you and much appreicated.

Comment: This is expected behaviour and is documented. Simply, you can't have multiple placeholders with the same name (and emulation should be turned off whenever possible imo). [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: @JonStirling, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@Jon Stirling**,

After reading those comment on [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Quote from **william dot clarke at gmail dot com**

> Surely if you want to use prepared statements that way you should use
>   the syntax in the second example:
>
> eg.
>
> instead of: select id,name from demo_de where name LIKE :name OR
>   name=:name
>
> use: select id,name from demo_de where name LIKE ? OR name=?
>
> I believe you are supposed to either use distinct named parameters
>   (name, name1) OR anonymous parameters (?s)

He answered my question about 9 years ago.

Hope this post will help someone who are looking for an answer.